# getting uploaded file name at node title

Tags: nodes, 7, files

Users will upload files.  The user will tag the file with a project name and some keywords and an optional text comment.  I have made a content-type called 'image', that has filed for title, file, project, keywords and comments.

I want the tile of the node to be the name of the uploaded file.  The name of the filed is 'file' the field is of type File, the widget is of type File, and the filed name is field_file.  I have the token module and the "Automatic Nodetitles" module.  The token module gives me token "node:field_file_body", this is not the file name.

How do I set the title of the each "image" node to the name of the uploaded file?

Comment: If you looking at just nodes then http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle is fine but if you are looking at the entity level to be used across all entity types then I would suggest http://drupal.org/project/auto_entitylabel which will most probably replace auto node title in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I also battled with this; this is my solution:

Use the [Automatic Nodetitles Module](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) as described by the others, and in the **Pattern for the title** text box load up the filefield and extract the filename that way. Example:

```
<?php
//Load the file
$file = file_load($node->field_document['und'][0]['fid']);

// Filename
return $file->filename;
?>
```

Obviously you need to check the **Evaluate PHP in pattern.** checkbox at the bottom for this to work, and replace "field_document" with the name of your own file field.

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 1):

You could try this module: [FileField Paths](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_paths). From the description, it looks like it might provide you with the tokens you need.

**Edit** Here's the code where it adds the tokens if you're interested: [see the repository](http://drupalcode.org/project/filefield_paths.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/modules/token.inc). If that's not what you need, it's probably pretty close to what you need.

**Edit 2** Looks like you'll have to create a module. Don't stress, it's not hard. This [blog post](http://mackstar.com/blog/2011/06/17/how-add-your-own-tokens-cck-fields-druapl-7) shows you how to create a module which provides custom tokens for nodes. You can combine that with the repository link in my first edit to acheive the token you need. If you've never created a module before, it's simple. Follow the simple tutorial on Drupal.org. All you need is a folder in sites/all/modules with the files mymodule.module and mymodule.info where "mymodule" is your module name.

Comment: I have FileField Paths module. There is no token for file_name or file_info just file_body.  I am still learning how to modify drupal and am somewhat at a loss.

Comment: I just added more info. I guess the "files" tokens are only available to fields. You need to add the token you need to the "node" area.

Comment: Joe - Are you using Drupal 6 or 7 BTW? Yeah at any rate for this to work, you should be using CCK filefield upload for D6 and Fields file upload for D7. I don't think you need to create a module, see my answer below. I just tested Auto Nodetitles Module and sure enough the File was available as a token for Auto Nodetitles

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @Jonathan Rowny said, you could also use the [Automatic Nodetitles Module](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle) and then use the `Token` of the uploaded file name as the auto node title. But you will also need the Token module installed / activated. I have used this method and it works great.

**Added:** screen capture from Auto Nodetitles that can use a token name of the file name.

[image]

[image: Token Replacement Patterns for Files]

Comment: Where is the file name token?  I look in the token lists for "Nodes" and all I can find is [node:field_file_body].  I have looked everywhere but not found anything with "file name".  I am using Drupal 7.

Comment: Whenever you use Token, you have "`Replacement Patterns`" contextual to where you are using tokens. See my screen capture I have added above.

Comment: Arghh.... I am missing something very basic.

Comment: Arghh.... I am missing something very basic.  I am using Drupal 7 I have a filed named "file" that is of type "File" that has a MySQL filed name of "field_file" and a widget of type "File".  I have modules "Token", "FileField Paths" and "Automaic NodeTitles".  My first screen lokks just like yours but I never get a "Replacement Patterns" area.  all I get is Name: File,  Token: [node:filed_file_body], Description: File field .  How do I amke Replacement Pattern appear?  I never get anything like your second screen.

Comment: Damn... How do I post an image to this site?

Comment: If I use Drupal 7 should I load CCK module (the only releases for CCK are Development releases for Drupal 7).  Will CCK give me the replacment tokens?

Comment: Joe you don't need CCK Module for Drupal 7, it's now built in as "Fields". It sounds like you are doing everything correctly. Are you sure you have all those modules enabled?

Comment: Yes, I carefully went over the modules and made sure all were enabled.  Where is the "replacement Patterns" found?  How do I post an image to this site so I can show what I see?  I am sure I am missing something very basic or else my combination of modules is screwing things up somehow.

Comment: You can edit your original question and click the image button to upload an image or post an image to a comment using a 3rd party image service.

Comment: OK, I think I know what the problem is.  I need to write a module (correct?).  I am looking for a token that does not exist in the node section until I write a module that puts it there (correct).  I was looking for a token in the page with the "automatic title generation" but there is non there of the file name, ... I have to write a module that will put the token there.  (correct?)

Comment: ah, it looks like there is an issue for this: http://drupal.org/node/691078?page=1 so it looks like, it's going to be hard to get this to work today but it looks promising that it will work.

Comment: ok... so this is a recognized bug in Tokens module.  I will skip the automatic titles, for now, and manually enter the node titles.  Any hint on when this issue will be fixed?  I am using Tokens 7.x-1.0-rc1 (I am OK with writing a module to fix the issue, but if the issue will be fixed in the next release of Tokens, I would much rather just wait.)

Comment: Well the issue was opened over a year ago but it seems like they are getting close. I've seen issues sometimes take a few years to get fixed, that's the pros / cons of open source, it's a community effort but sometimes things are a little slow to move. If you think you can write a module to fix it why not and then perhaps contribute back to drupa.org with a sandbox project.

Comment: I don't think the community would want my module that moves one field (file name), into the Nodes area.  I have written 2 trial modules and FAR from a master module coder.  The issue is marked as a "Major" bug in the Tokens module, so they will probably fix it "soon".  My boss is cool with me saying that the issue is a Drupal module bug.  I will just manually enter file names as titles for now.

Comment: ok i see what you are saying, seems like a good short term solution then.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with Automatic Nodetitles, Token, and Entity Token.  I used the following token:

`[node:field-file:file]`

As you described in the question, I have a field called `file` in my nodetype.  I believe the `:file` portion of the token was created by Entity Token.